# What is the need of .ppk file while connecting EC2 node through putty? can we access all other instances with same .ppk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

What is the need of .ppk file while connecting EC2 node through putty?

```
      1:can we access all other instances with same .ppk? (or)
      2:we should create one .ppk file per instance?
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually its needed cause Amazon doesn't have password system for SSH accesss it uses key pair private and public so you need the key to loggin in EC2 via .ppk.

No you can't login with this key in other instance unless you have selected it during deploying server

http://www.cmsthisway.com/build-amazon-ec2-rds-mysql-server/